# Trying to scrape from an unspecified amount of web pages, exception isn't being thrown

Tags: python, loops, exception

I'm working through a python course on udemy and we're doing a section on website parsing. This particular exercise wants us to parse multiple pages of a website of which we **do not know** how many pages there are in total.

My thought process was to create a try and except block, except I cannot get the exception to print anything. I'm a newbie, so this could very well be a very silly mistake. Here is my code. It works to get the primary job done which is to grab all unique authors from each page and append to a list, but I want it to stop trying to parse when we reach a page that doesn't exist. I know that the website has 10 pages, but I set range from 1-19 just to see if my code would throw an exception once it got to a page that isnt there.

```
import requests
import bs4

authors = []

try: 
    valid_page = True
    for n in range(1,20):
        
        base_url =  'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{}/'
        scrape_url = base_url.format(n)
        res = requests.get(scrape_url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
        
        for item in soup.select('.author'):
            unique_author = item.text
            
            if unique_author not in authors:
                authors.append(unique_author)
    
except exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    valid_page = False
```

Comment: Have you manually tried to view any of the pages you think should cause the exception? Or the last "valid" page?

Comment: @goalie1998 ah, good point. I just looked, and those pages do exist but they just have text that says "no quotes found" on them.

Comment: Exactly. If you look at the last "valid" page, you'll see there is no ```Next``` button. You can use that as an indication whether or not to continue your loop. (You can use a while loop instead of a for loop so you don't have to worry about the actual number of pages)

Comment: @goalie1998 Can you help me visualize the while loop? Thanks for your help so far